# How to update database Item using the Notion API

Tags: python, notion-api

I am currently trying to update a value in a Notion Data base but i am only able to update the header row and not the value fields. Also when getting a specific database using its id only the header values are returned and not the values that are inside the data base.
This is the code i am currently using to update the data base header value

```
payloadUpdateDataBase = {"properties":{"Ticket ID":{"name": "New Ticket ID"},},}

headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Notion-Version": "2022-02-22",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

def updateDatabase():
    response = requests.request("PATCH", urlSingleDataBase, json=payloadUpdateDataBase, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
```

Does any one know how to get/update the values inside the database and not only the headers?

Answer (score 1):

Every entry within a database is a `page` itself and can be as such manipulated using the usual `pages` endpoint. By querying the database, you can get the `page_id` needed to do so. On the other hand, each entry can be treated as a `block`. If you want to manipulate the content and different child blocks, you can use the `page_id` as `block_id` for the `blocks` endpoint.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32623801)

Comment: It does indeed provide the answer to his question - by updating the pages you'll update the values inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

The [readme.md file in the pynotion project](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py#example-working-with-databases-aka-collections-tables-boards-etc) has more information about this, but you can use:

```py
from notion.client import NotionClient

client = NotionClient(token_v2="<your token>")
cv     = client.get_collection_view("<The url of your table>")

for i in rows:
    if i.get_property("Name") == "<The name of the row you want to modify>":
        i.set_property("State", "To-do")
```

Unfortunately, the main repository is not being maintained for the past 2 years, so there's a bug preventing the prior code to run, but it can be easily fixed following [this Github comment](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/issues/365#issuecomment-1041977974)!

Aditionally, you can get the available properties and their options in a programatic way with:

```py
props = cv.collection.get_schema_properties()
```